# Dictionary changes without obvious reason

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I am trying to create a trivia game for learning reasons but something odd happens with my dictionary that I cannot understand.

The code that I generally tested to see how things work is this:

```
cat = {
    'easy': {
        'books': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=10&difficulty=easy&type=boolean',
        'films': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=11&difficulty=easy&type=boolean',
        'general knowledge': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=boolean',
        'music': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=12&difficulty=easy&type=boolean',
        'science & nature': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=17&difficulty=easy&type=boolean',
        'sports': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=21&difficulty=easy&type=boolean'
    },
    'medium': {
        'books': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=10&difficulty=medium&type=boolean',
        'films': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=11&difficulty=medium&type=boolean',
        'general knowledge': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=boolean',
        'music': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=12&difficulty=medium&type=boolean',
        'science & nature': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=17&difficulty=medium&type=boolean',
        'sports': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=21&difficulty=medium&type=boolean'
    }
}

print(cat)

for level in cat:
    print(level)

catselect = []
while catselect not in ("1", "2"):
    catselect = input("Select a category, for easy press 1, for medium press 2: ")

    if catselect == "1":
        selectedcat = "easy"
    elif catselect == "2":
        selectedcat = "medium"
    print(f"You selected the {selectedcat} difficulty level")

    print("The subjects can be: ")
    for i, cat[selectedcat] in enumerate(cat[selectedcat]):
        print(i, cat[selectedcat])

print(cat)
```

So when at the end the code is running the cat dictionary is not the same any
more and I don't have any reasoning this may happen.

This is what I see:

```
{'easy': {'books': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=10&difficulty=easy&type=boolean', 'films': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=11&difficulty=easy&type=boolean', 'general knowledge': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=boolean', 'music': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=12&difficulty=easy&type=boolean', 'science & nature': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=17&difficulty=easy&type=boolean', 'sports': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=21&difficulty=easy&type=boolean'}, 'medium': {'books': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=10&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'films': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=11&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'general knowledge': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'music': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=12&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'science & nature': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=17&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'sports': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=21&difficulty=medium&type=boolean'}}
easy
medium
Select a category, for easy press 1, for medium press 2: 1
You selected the easy difficulty level
The subjects can be: 
0 general knowledge
1 books
2 films
3 music
4 sports
5 science & nature
{'easy': 'science & nature', 'medium': {'general knowledge': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'books': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=10&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'films': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=11&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'music': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=12&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'sports': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=21&difficulty=medium&type=boolean', 'science & nature': 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50&category=17&difficulty=medium&type=boolean'}}
```

Where did all the categories for `easy` go? Why do I end up with `'science & nature'` instead?

Comment: Is it the order of the dictionary items that has changed? If so that is because of the way dictionaries in python themselves are structured as they don't retain the insertion order you initially gave them. A built in python dictionary is a key - value lookup table. Keys in your case question categories are hashed which does not maintain order. If order is important maybe take a look at OrderedDicts in the collections library.

Comment: @darcycp: no, it’s not a dictionary ordering issue. I updated the question to include the output to illustrate better what happens. Also, as of Python 3.6 and up dictionaries *do* retain the insertion order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning back to the dictionary here:

```
for i, cat[selectedcat] in enumerate(cat[selectedcat]):
```

You are asking the `for` loop to assign to `i` **and `cat[selectedcat]`**. Don't do that.

The above is essentially doing this:

```
iterator = iter(enumerate(cat[selectedcat]))
while True:
    try:
        next_item = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    i, cat[selectedcat] = next_item
```

and so assigns each value from `cat[selectedcat]` *to `cat[selectedcat]` itself*.

It happens to work, because the original dictionary referenced by `cat[selectedcat]` is still being referenced by the `enumerate()` object, and so all its keys are still being produced in the loop. But the `cat` dictionary itself is being asked to replace the value for the `selectedcat` key with each of the category strings in turn. You can see this happen, because you then *print* the new value for `cat[selectedcat]` inside the loop.

If you wanted to show the values with numbers, you want to use a different, new variable name for the loop, e.g.:

```
for i, category in enumerate(cat[selectedcat]):
    print(i, category)
```

Here, `category` is a new variable (just like `i` is).

Comment: I appreciate your comment! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
    for i, cat[selectedcat] in enumerate(cat[selectedcat]):
```

Each time through the loop it assigns an element of `cat[selectedcat]` to `cat[selectedcat]`, which modifies the dictionary. So the first time through the loop, it does

```
cat[selectedcat] = cat[selectedcat][0]
```

When the loop completes, the value of `cat[selectedcat]` will be the last element of `cat[selectedcat]`.

You should normally use ordinary variables for your loop variables:

```
for i, value in enumerate(cat[selectedcat]):
    print(i, value)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the quick answer and the reasoning why it happens! I really appreciate it :)